# EF6 With TT Templates Guid is returning null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2008

I have set in my sql server 2008 that I want a unique idenitifier and that the default value is to be

[image]

And in my edmx

[image]

I never had an issue with this in EF5 it always set it fine why in ef6 is it being returned as null ie its displaying as

> 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change [`StoreGeneratedPattern`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.metadata.edm.storegeneratedpattern(v=vs.110).aspx) to `Identity`

Comment: Why has this changed though i never had to set this in ef5 is their any docs to support this change.